# I need to create a snowflake dummy stored procedure with output array as push

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I need  to snowflake how to create dummy stored procedure with out put array as push in snowflake.

Answer (score 1):

Dummy stored procedure using Snowflake Scripting:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dummy()
RETURNS ARRAY
LANGUAGE SQL
AS
$$
begin
   return ARRAY_CONSTRUCT(1,2,3);
end;
$$;

CALL dummy();
-- [   1,   2,   3 ]


DESC RESULT LAST_QUERY_ID();
-- name  type  kind
-- DUMMY ARRAY COLUMN
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you mentioned pushing to the array, I'll add to Lukasz's answer to show a JavaScript example with pushing to the array in a loop:

```
create or replace procedure ARRAY_SAMPLE()
returns array
language javascript
as
$$

    var arr = [];
    
    var rs = snowflake.execute({sqlText:'select N_NAME from SNOWFLAKE_SAMPLE_DATA.TPCH_SF1.NATION'});
    
    while (rs.next()) {
        arr.push(rs.getColumnValue('N_NAME'));
    }

    return arr;
    
$$;

call ARRAY_SAMPLE();
```